# Why RowVersion property is not raising optimistic concurrency exception when two concurrent changes occur?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, optimistic-concurrency

I have the following entity,

```
 public class PatientRegistry : BaseEntity {

        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Display(Name = "Patient File Number")]
        public long PatientFileId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PartnerRegistry> Partners { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string AliasName { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateNow { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    }
```

and the BaseEntity is,

```
 public class BaseEntity : ISoftDelete {
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }
```

the entity has `RowVersion` property and I use the fluent API to configure it as RowVersion. I use the repository pattern and this is how I load the entity in the context,

```
 public async Task<PatientRegistry> GetPatient(long Id, bool isPartners = true, bool isUser = true) {
            if (isPartners && !isUser)
              return await context.PatientsRegistry
                .IgnoreQueryFilters()
                .Include(pt => pt.Partners)
                .Include(pt => pt.User)
                .Include(pt => pt.User.Gender)
                .Include(pt => pt.User.Nationality)
                .Include(pt => pt.User.Occupation)
                .Include(pt => pt.User.Ethnicity)
                .Include(pt => pt.User.MaritalStatus)
                .Include(pt => pt.User.Country)
                .Include(pt => pt.User.State)
                .Include(pt => pt.User.City)
                .Include(pt => pt.User.Database)
                .Include(pt => pt.User.UserAvatar)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(pt => pt.PatientFileId == Id);
        }
```

and in my controller, I update as following,

```
[HttpPut("{FileId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdatePatient([FromRoute] PatientFileIdResource fileIdModel, [FromBody] SavePatientsRegistryResource model)
{
    ApiSuccessResponder<PatientRegistryResource> response = new ApiSuccessResponder<PatientRegistryResource>();
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    Task<PatientRegistry> getPatientTask = repository.GetPatient(fileIdModel.FileId.Value);
    Task<RequestHeaderResource> getHeaderRequestTask = headerRequestService.GetUserHeaderData();
    await Task.WhenAll(getPatientTask, getHeaderRequestTask);
    PatientRegistry patient = await getPatientTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
    RequestHeaderResource header = await getHeaderRequestTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (patient == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The patient does not exist in the database");
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    patient.DateNow = DateTime.Now;
    patient.AliasName = model.AliasName;
    await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync(header);
    return StatusCode(200, response);
}
```

Now if I access the same record with two different users and one of the alters `AliasName` and saves the second user that accessed the record will still be able to save new changes without I get a concurrency exception. why are the concurrent updates here not raising an update exception?

this is the Fluent API config,

```
 builder.Entity<PatientRegistry>()
        .Property(a => a.RowVersion).IsRowVersion()
        .IsConcurrencyToken()
        .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```

I have the update log [here](https://gist.github.com/embryologist/990a703085957d09959e169137d2f6fb)

**UPDATE**

**For future reference,**

Based on the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency), we can test for concurrency conflict by just manipulating one of the values before calling save.

i.e.

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.PatientsRegistry SET AliasName = 'Jane' WHERE PatientFileId = 2222");
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

this will raise up an exception.

Comment: no, they haven't, but should not EF tell that the second user's RowVersion is lower than the new one and reject the changes?

Comment: you are right, I had a misconception about how it works, I must misunderstand what is mentioned [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/concurrency)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the read from second user is **after** the write from first user then the second user's `RowVersion` will reflect the value at the time (i.e. **after** the first update). Thus - no concurrency issue.

You will only get an issue if they both read (and thus get the same `RowVersion`) and **then** both try and write.